# Pokemon Black 2 Emulator save issue

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, emulation, pokemon-black-2-white-2

So here's my situation now. I've started a Pokemon Black 2 game on Desmume, and the game warned me that I already have a saved game, so I said I want to start a new game anyway.

Now, I'm usually saving with states, so I usually don't mind not being able to save normally.

However, in Black 2, I reached the part where I'm required to shoot a movie (right after the second gym battle), now it requires me to save, and it tells me "You can't save the game because there's already a saved game, **please press SELECT+UP+B at the start menu**".

Now, I obviously don't want to completely erase my saved game, so I tried the following:

- Remove the saved file from the Battery folder and restarting the game.
- Rename the game and the saved state file and restarting.

Needless to say these didn't work, I'm suspecting the saved state has the current save file in memory and the emulator won't read it again.

Is there some way I can force it to? Is there perhaps a cheat code that would allow me to bypass the guard at the entrance (and if I do that, would the game allow me to move forward?). Is it possible to perhaps convert the saved state to an actual save file?

Comment: I don't really get the problem - you are using save-states right? So it should be no problem to follow the games instructions (press SELECT+UP+B at the start menu). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @5pike: Ah, but then I do that, and reload the saved state, and it still won't let me save. As if the saved state doesn't know I did that.

Comment: A savestate is nothing more than a RAM dump. If you can't save on your current savestate, there's not much you can do to fix it. If starting a new game is required, then unfortunately that's what you'll have to do.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Oh, I see. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Does it not show effort? Not well formatted? Please provide an explanation so that I may improve it.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I'm gonna guess its because this topic (emulators) is a very gray area in regards to piracy.

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden: I have already purchased the game, I've downloaded and used an emulator to further explore the game without the overhead of the grinding involved (i.e. using cheats and/or save alteration software). That's what I usually do, I actually finished the game a while back on my DS.

Comment: The community can be cagey when it comes to legal grey areas, but as you own the game and are emulating it legally, there's no problem. The question itself is fine :)

Comment: You're saying the save state no longer works? If you can I would use an earlier save state to go back, and just use the in-game save system. Seeing as DeSmuME has no problem doing it.

Comment: @Scootaloo: You don't understand the issue. The issue is that I already have a different game saved in the in-game file, and because it already exists in the save state (even though I started a new game), it won't let me ingame save. And that's now required to continue with the story.

Comment: As per the [meta] post, [What's the official stance on console emulation?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/102/4797) - questions about emulation or emulators are perfectly on-topic in Arqade.

Comment: @5pike and Madara: if the emulator ties save states and save files, then there's likely a way to explicitly dump a save file to an external file, then load it back.

Comment: @badp - Probably. Could be in the settings. Would have to dust off Desmume and go check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't over write the save that is already on the game, which you got the warning message about  when it said" **"please press SELECT+UP+B at the start menu.**" so, if you want to save in game you have to start again and follow that command to be able to save after.

With the legit version of black I had the same problem, I bought a 2nd hand version and I got to the first gym and couldn't save, I had to restart the DS delete the save file and then I was able to save.

### Direct Answer

No, you can't you have to start the game but before you can start a **"New Game"** you have to follow the **"please press SELECT+UP+B at the start menu.**" command

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to fix your save file at that point, but I resolved the same issue by using a walk through walls cheat to get past the guy. The game resumed as usual once I got through.

Answer (score -1):

Save states includes all of the contents of a game's memory, **including your in-game save.** You only have three choices to be able to save again: first is to restart the emulator and delete your save file (which means all your progress is lost), second is to hack your save state to remove your in-game save, and the third is to use a cheat code (I will not recommend any form of cheating, it is up to you to decide) to get past the guy.

It is not possible to convert directly your save state to an in-game save file though, but if you know how save files work, you might be able to create your own save file from your save state (but that is no longer conversion).

Comment: To downvoter: care to explain why you downvoted? I also want some suggestion how I can improve my answer. Thanks. :)